# How do I make my perspective grid fit the width of the artboard in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids

For some reason when I open perspective grid, the grid is really small (pictured). How do i resize it so it fills up the artboard?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to menu **View** → **Perspective Grid** → **Define Grid** and change the **Viewing Distance** and the **Horizon Height**

[image]

Comment: Viewing distance is greyed out. Cant change it

Answer (score 0):

Use the perspective tool (Shift+P) and drag the anchor points on the perspective grid to move it and change it's size.